# Linking Keycloak accounts through Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I was wondering if there is a way to Link a Broker realm user to the provider through the keycloak library in spring boot.

Situation:
When we log in with a user through the realm provider, keycloak identifies their existence in the broker (or creates them) and then an email is sent to the accounts link.
But the way I use keycloak, I have a service responsible for creating these to customize them for the application. In other words, when a user is created through this SpringBoot service, the idea is to check the existence of the realm provider and link the user created in the broker there.

**Question:
Is it possible to link the broker's account with an existing one in the provider programmatically?**

Additional:
it is possible to add the link directly through the admin console, so there must be a way to do it programmatically.

[Image of manual creation of account link in admin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuvLZ.png)

I tried using the setSocialLinks method or the setFederatedIdentities method but it doesn't seem to work.

```java
FederatedIdentityRepresentation federatedIdentity = new FederatedIdentityRepresentation();

federatedIdentity.setIdentityProvider(super.getProviderRealmName());
federatedIdentity.setUserId(providerUserId);
federatedIdentity.setUserName(user.getUsername());

user.setFederatedIdentities(Collections.singletonList(federatedIdentity));
                
Response brokerResult = brokerUserResource.create(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's an [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0CPJ.png) to do it automatically already on the Authentication flow configuration